# Create an array from get-child item list quicky in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, split

I am trying to shorten my scripts and reduce the number of `foreach` I use. I have a list of items using Get-ChildItem and I'd like to split each filename and create an array from the total list.

Example directory:

```
\\path\file1.name1.example1.jpg
\\path\file2.name2.example2.jpg
\\path\file3.name3.example3.jpg
```

Desired Outcome:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

Current Script:

```
#get-child item of all files in hte path
$files = get-childitem "\\Path\" -Recurse
    $filenames = $files.Name.Split(".")[0]
```

Also tried:

```
#get-child item of all files in hte path
$files = get-childitem "\\Path\" -Recurse
    $filenames =  @($files.Name).Split(".")[0]
```

Of course, the above only produces `file1` rather than part 0 of the `split` for each item in $files. Is there a way to get the desired outcome in a single pass without adding additional `foreach` actions to `split` each file one at a time?

Comment: "[...] and reduce the number of `foreach` I use" - why?

Comment: mostly in an attempt to learn new commands and functions. I've also found it's easier for me to hand scripts off for my co-workers to modify for their own needs when there's not a ton of nesting.

YOur answer below makes a ton of sense and i think integrating foreach-object is the way to go rather than depending on foreach loops.

Thanks so much, very helpful as always.

Comment: As an exercise in forcing yourself to take better advantage of pipeline semantics (and "try something new") it makes perfect sense - `foreach(...){}` is great for already-materialized collections, but the pipeline is king when it comes to "streaming" data :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply most native operators to *collections*, so we can avoid explicit loops if we just rewrite your string manipulation routine to something that accomplished the same in a single operator call - like `-replace` for example:

```
$fileNames = (Get-ChildItem "\\Path\" -Recurse).Name -replace '\..*$'
```

The regular expression `\..*$` will match the first literal `.` and remove it along with everything after.

---

While `$collection -replace $pattern` is generally faster than `$collection |ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $pattern}`, this might not actually be the most efficient approach - the grouping of `Get-ChildItem ...` in `()` means that we're *waiting* for `Get-ChildItem` to finish enumerating all files before we can start operating on the resulting array.

If you want the *first result* as fast as possible, take advantage of the pipeline and `ForEach-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "\\Path\" -Recurse |ForEach-Object {
  $_.Split('.')[0]
}
```

Unlike the `foreach(...){}` loop statement, the commands in a PowerShell pipeline execute *consecutively*, meaning that `ForEach-Object` can start operating on the first output item from `Get-ChildItem` long before `Get-ChildItem` is done.

My advice: Try both and *measure the difference* (either using `Measure-Command`, or something more fancy, like [PSProfiler](https://github.com/IISResetMe/PSProfiler)) - results may vary wildly, depending on your input and how you structure subsequent work on the resulting data